# Remove not int elements in list

Tags: python

Hi I have this task in python and I should remove all not int elements, the result of the code down below is `[2, 3, 1, [1, 2, 3]]` and I have no idea why in the result the list is not moved away. Only tested suggestions please, I mean working ones.

```
# Great! Now use .remove() and/or del to remove the string, 
# the boolean, and the list from inside of messy_list. 
# When you're done, messy_list should have only integers in it
messy_list = ["a", 2, 3, 1, False, [1, 2, 3]]
for ele in messy_list:  
   print('the type of {} is  {} '.format(ele,type(ele)))
   if type(ele) is not int:
     messy_list.remove(ele)
     print(messy_list)
```

Comment: Do you want the list removed? Or flattened

Comment: Don't modify the list you're iterating over.

Comment: You're modifying the list while iterating over it. That behaviour is undefined. In particular, in this case, it seems that it removes `False`, therefore moving the list into `False`'s old position, and then finds that the next index is out of bounds for the list. You should create a new list, or really, use a list comprehension.

Comment: @MeesdeVries The behaviour is defined and consistent, it's just not intuitive so not recommended

Comment: @Chris_rands, my bad, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
>>> messy_list = ["a", 2, 3, 1, False, [1, 2, 3]]
>>> [elem for elem in messy_list if type(elem) == int]
[2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: `type(1)` is just `int`

Comment: @Chris_Rands isn't that OP wants? Title says - Remove not int elements from list

Comment: I think `if type(elem) is int` might be better in this case

Comment: Yes but why would you call `type(1)` every time, when you know the type is `int`?  just use `type(elem) == int`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not related to the presence of a list inside your `messy_list`, but rather to the fact you are modifying the list while iterating over it.

For example, with `messy_list = ["a", 2, 3, 1, False, "a"]` you would get `[2, 3, 1, "a"]` as a result.

On the other hand:
`[elem for elem in messy_list if type(elem) == int]`
returns `[2, 3, 1]`, which is what you want.